# Quoted field extraction

Tags: linux, sh

I have a file:

```
"test 1" blub ha
```

And I want to retrieve the first field `"test 1"` in sh. Now using e.g. `cut` or `awk`, they always ignore the quotation.
What tool can do a field extraction with actual honoring quotations?

**EDIT**:

For the people not familiar with quoting in shell the following cases should be handled as one field:

- `"Test 1"`
- `'test 1'`
- `test_1`

Comment: what do you want to do with it? place it in a variable? keep only that one?

Comment: `$ echo '"test 1" blub ha' | cut -d" " -f-2` returns `"test 1"` to me. Would that suffice?

Comment: Place it in a variable.

Comment: Is it always the first field? Is it always two words? Is it always quoted?

Comment: @LevLevitsky None of your requirements.

Comment: What's the logic then? How do you know which field you need?

Comment: @fedorqui This does however not seem to work when the first one is not quoted

Comment: @LevLevitsky The first one.

Comment: @abergmeier could you update your question indicating what you mean with "when the first one is not quoted"? It is not clear to me all the cases you want to cover.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `sed`:

```
var=`sed -r -e "s/^([\"'][^\"']+[\"']).*/\1/" -e "s/^([^\"'][^ ]*).*/\1/" file`
```

The first expression looks for a line starting with a quote and keeps only the first quoted expression.

The second one looks for a line starting with a non-quote, and keeps characters until the first space.

Comment: The OP also seems to want to respect singly-quoted fields.